# Delete xmlns="" and ns1: from XML-File using VB.Net

Tags: xml, excel, vb.net

Help me please with this problem:
I have Excel-file and try to generate XML-file using VB.Net and XDocument/XML Literals...
After generating there is a file:

```
....
<Payload>
        <ns1:BidSet xmlns="http://... xmlns:ns0="http://.... xmlns:ns1="http://....>        
            <tradingDate xmlns="">2016-10-31</tradingDate>
            <PTPObligation xmlns="">
            ....
            ....
            </PTPObligation>
        </ns1:BidSet>
</Payload>
....
```

empty But I need to delete here empty `xmlns=""` from all tags(nodes) and delete `ns1:` from all nodes.
I do this using the coed:

```
 Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(False)

        Dim Input = File.ReadAllText(outfile)
        Dim output = Regex.Replace(Input, "(ns1:)", "")
        File.WriteAllText(outfile, output)

        Dim AllElements =
        From elem In xdoc.Descendants()
        Where elem.Name = NameOfBid
        Select elem

        For Each elem As XElement In AllElements

            If elem.Name.NamespaceName = "" Then
                elem.Attributes("xmlns").Remove()
                elem.Name = elem.Parent.Name.Namespace + elem.Name.LocalName

                Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(outfile, settings)
                    xdoc.Save(writer)
                End Using
            End If
        Next
```

But Excel-file has a lot of Rows and XML-file has a lot of Nodes which should be processed.
And this program works too long.
Is it possible to delete all that i need but faster using VB.Net (or maybe C#-code)?

Comment: you can generate an xml file in the same way to generate a text file

Comment: how is that ? using what ?

Comment: How you generate this xml in first place. it is maybe possible to generate it without namespaces

Comment: thanks to the `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` fucntion, for example